# Génitif de l'anglais en français

Tags: traduction, anglais, génitif

Je me demande comment traduire le génitif de l'anglais comme par exemple dans la phrase ci-dessous :

> Do not suggest that the author includes citations to your (**or your associates’**) work.
>
> Ne suggérez pas que l’auteur inclue des citations de votre travail (**ou de celui de vos collaborateurs**).

Est-ce qu'il y une autre façon plus compacte pour interpréter la structure du génitif avec l'apostrophe ?

Comment: On utilise plutôt le pluriel « travaux », ce qui permet d'économiser un caractère :-) On dirait en fait « que l'auteur cite vos travaux », mais ça fait disparaître la préposition, qui était peut-être le point qui t’intéressait ?

Comment: @StéphaneGimenez Merci. En effet ma question concerne la structure anglaise **or your associates’** (génitif avec s) et comment l'interpréter en français.

Comment: Le génitif est toujours là mais la structure est un peu moins lourde car on n'a pas besoin de répéter la préposition précédente : « que l'auteur cite vos travaux (ou ceux de vos collaborateurs) ». Il n'y a plus qu'un *de*.

Comment: @StéphaneGimenez Parfait. Si tu veux tu peux donner ton commentaire comme réponse afin que je la choisisses.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a problem with your sentence (Are you the one that made it up?); there are in English 3 forms of the present tense, which I list in the following, each with an example or more;

- state present

> The sun rises always in the East. This writer puts too much emphasis on his statements. Apples are a delicious fruit.

- historic present

> She begins her carreer in 1982; after a few professional mistakes, fate smiles at her and she begins climbing up the ladder, but not for long as she becomes ill.

- present of narration

> Wilbert catches Heinrich by the waist…Heinrich falls…gets back on his feet, deals Wilbert a side kick, Wilbert falls, he is hurt…

Obviously, your sentence makes use of the state present, and as such either it is flawed or there is a semantic flaw in the translation.

1. It is flawed if you consider the translation right, in other words if you consider that the translation is what you want to say, that is that something is being suggested; the rendering of your French sentence is then as follows, there is not the possibility of an other tense: in particular, the state present does not fit the case;

Do not suggest that the author **should include** citations from your (or your associates’) work.

However the French sentence would have been somewhat better formulated as "Ne suggérer pas que l’auteur doive inclure des citations de vos travaux (ou de ceux de vos collaborateurs).

2. If you consider that the English sentence is right, then you cannot have the French translation you come up with; the meaning of it is a possible one but it asks for a far fetched context: you suggest **the possibility that someone could be including** citations. However what it seems plain you want to express is as follows;

> N'insinuez pas que l'auteur inclue/incluerait des citations de vos travaux (ou de ceux de vos collaborateurs).

There is a great enough difference between to suggest" and "to insinuate".

As to what concerns the possessive case it is well translated and there is no other, more compact means of putting it.

Comment: Merci pour la réponse. Bien que je détienne un diplôme de maîtrise d'anglais (C2) ça fait une décennie que je ne l'étudie pas. Tu m'as fait rappeler plusieurs choses. Ce n'est pas moi qui a écrit la version originale. Je l'ai vue dans un site d'une révue scientifique. Par contre c'est moi qui a essayé de la traduire en français.

Comment: @dimitris Est-ce que mon explication est assez  convaincante ou est-ce qu'elle resterait plutôt obscure sur certains points?

Comment: Techniquement, cela répond à la question, mais il faut attendre la dernière phrase de la réponse pour cela, le reste n'est qu'une grosse digression fortement axée sur la langue anglaise ou la traduction de cette phrase d'exemple.